# Fastest way to communicate between a kubernetes pod and his host?

Tags: kubernetes, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ipc

i'm setting up a kubernetes node and searching the fastest way to communicate (IPC) between a host and a pod. (IP/TCP is to slow)

My first thought was to write an own character device driver as Virtual File System but a could'nt find a way to set this up correctly inside a kubernetes domain.. (HostPath / storage volumes?)

Because of a realtime requirement TCP/IP is not the best technology for this (in my opinion)

I'd like to control the access to the real time data. That's why i don't want to use Shared Memory directly for this purpose

Is kubectl supporting own shared character drivers between host and PODs?

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: As you've stated your requirements, I don't think you want Kubernetes or even Docker; just run your processes directly on the host so they can access the data source directly.  Kubernetes works better in environments where you can tolerate processes running with no visibility to their host and where you can tolerate a latency hit from a multi-layered TCP-oriented network setup.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! I want to protect the host system, so that the user application has no access to the base system -> **container technology** And i thought i don't want to develop my own deployment environment and use a free deployment tool-> **Kubernetes** I know this is not the normal use case for kubernetes. But maybe someone has experience with it and can help me out to it set up for this special purpose :)

Comment: The standard use case for Kubernetes is that you _really_ have no access to the host – you wouldn't know of any specific host process you could communicate with via a non-TCP path, and your container usually wouldn't be pinned to any specific node.